# What should be included in a Docker container to deploy a ASP.NET web application?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to understand `Docker`.

So far I get that `Docker` creates packages of our applications called `containers` with all the dependencies needed to run our applications. Then, the `DevOps` use these `containers` to deploy the applications.

I'm comfortable with the high-level overview, but, in the case of a `ASP.NET` web application, what would be included in the `container`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your Dockerfile would look like.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```